# Let download file if authenticated

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've a RewriteRule in .htaccess file:

`RewriteRule ^folder/(.*)$ folder/handle.php?path=$1 [L]`

To authenticate users with `handle.php` file and see if they've premium accounts or not.

I want to **[1]** check if the user is not authenticated then page show an error, `otherwise` **[2]** download get start & I don't want to use any PHP class or script to handle files downloading (just normal server side downloading without php handling).

How can I achieve that? Is it possible?

*A URL to request a file download : `http://mywebsite.com/folder/file.zip`*

Comment: That rewrite rule pretty much implies that you want and are trying to use PHP to control the file download.

Comment: I have no idea what you have in mind, but if you require a php-page to check if someone is authenticated, it is logical to use a small php page to send the data to the user. If they are authenticated, send the appropiate header and then the content of the file. If they aren't, either just exit() out of the script (empty response) or include the error page.

Comment: its possible with rewrite, but normal server-side downloading should be changed to php handling :)

Comment: @Andrew but i want only control the authentication!

Comment: @Sumurai8 I used a php class to download files already. It has resume ability too! but i don't know why download speed is low and IDM connection to the link increasing slowly (in the case of 8 connections)

Comment: @revo Yes, BUT if you route to a PHP script you will have to use PHP to download the file, you can't avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

The rewrite rule you have there is fine... except you should probably add a condition to check and make sure the REQUEST is not "handle.php" - otherwise you may get a redirect loop.

Now, in your handle.php file - this is handling ALL files request in that folder.

In handle.php, you can use `$_GET['path']` to get the requested file name. While in handle.php, you can include your authentication checks. If the authentication check passes, you can then continue to `readfile` to the user. An example of handle.php:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
session_start();
include "../some_functions_auth_file.php";

// NOTE: better file checking should be implemented here. We're using basename() for now.
$file = !empty($_GET['path']) ? basename($_GET['path']) : false;
if($file === false || !file_exists($file)) die("Invalid file.");

if(user_is_authenticated()) {
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); 
  header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s")." GMT"); 
  header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
  header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false ); 
  header("Pragma: no-cache" ); 
  header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
  header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($file)) );
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
  header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\n");
  readfile($file);
  exit;
} else {
  header("Location: ../login.php");
}
?>
```

*Note that this is very basic and untested*

Now, if you don't want to use `readfile` (because it's, well, slow), then perhaps you could set an Apache environment variable... then, while in .htaccess, you could check if that variable exists - and if so, allow the download. Otherwise redirect the user to a login.

Comment: does it let users resume downloads?

Comment: No - that would take some extra coding and is fairly slower as it uses fread. But here's a good example if you must: http://www.richnetapps.com/php-download-script-with-resume-option/